# Reading columns using WHERE clause on MS Access passing combobox textvalue

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2003, oledbdataadapter

I am working on a windows application written in C# and using MS Access 2003 as my database. I am facing strange problem, when I write the query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE columnname='"+combobox.text+"'
```

and execute using oledbadapter, the dataset visualizer doesn't recognise the `where` clause and returns empty table.  Whereas

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE columnname='"+integervalue+"
```

will return the filtered column.

Here is my code snippet:

```
private void viewinfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
    OleDbCommand cmd;
    string schoolname = cmbschoolname.Text;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select  * from tblmedic where medicalschool ='"+combobox.text+"'", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

output: returns empty table when I pass the text value in the where-clause.

Comment: I would recommend using the debugger to figure out what "select  * from tblmedic where medicalschool ='"+combobox.text+"'" resolves to and trying it in Access to see if you get any errors. One possible issue is that you are not parametrizing your sql statement, so if any of the values in the combobox have a ' in them, the query will not work.

Comment: thank u for ur quick reply.i am not familiar with parametrizing the sql statement using  access database.could u please show me some snippet for where clause with text values being passed as parameters to database.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue.  it was the case of empty spaces in my access 2003 table columns. so used a trim() to clear the spaces while selecting the columns in where clause.

```
private void viewinfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
    OleDbCommand cmd;
    string schoolname = cmbschoolname.Text;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select  * from tblmedic where medicalschool ='"+combobox.text.ToString().Trim()+"'", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Sometimes silly mistakes makes u crave like anything :-)

:-)